# How to modify an add_action() inside a loop of core function

Tags: hooks, buddypress, user-registration

Ok I want to edit bp_core_screen_signup() is which is a function of buddypress that used to process the registration form. Basically this funtion checks for any errors produced and then loops through them using add_action() to inject them into register.php. Well I need to change the html tags it's using and I don't understand how. So first here is this big nasty function.

```
function bp_core_screen_signup() {
global $bp;

if ( !bp_is_current_component( 'register' ) )
    return;

// Not a directory
bp_update_is_directory( false, 'register' );

// If the user is logged in, redirect away from here
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( bp_is_component_front_page( 'register' ) )
        $redirect_to = trailingslashit( bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . bp_get_members_root_slug() );
    else
        $redirect_to = bp_get_root_domain();

    bp_core_redirect( apply_filters( 'bp_loggedin_register_page_redirect_to', $redirect_to ) );

    return;
}

$bp->signup->step = 'request-details';

if ( !bp_get_signup_allowed() ) {
    $bp->signup->step = 'registration-disabled';

// If the signup page is submitted, validate and save
} elseif ( isset( $_POST['signup_submit'] ) && bp_verify_nonce_request( 'bp_new_signup' ) ) {

    do_action( 'bp_signup_pre_validate' );

    // Check the base account details for problems
    $account_details = bp_core_validate_user_signup( $_POST['signup_username'], $_POST['signup_email'] );

    // If there are errors with account details, set them for display
    if ( !empty( $account_details['errors']->errors['user_name'] ) )
        $bp->signup->errors['signup_username'] = $account_details['errors']->errors['user_name'][0];

    if ( !empty( $account_details['errors']->errors['user_email'] ) )
        $bp->signup->errors['signup_email'] = $account_details['errors']->errors['user_email'][0];

    // Check that both password fields are filled in
    if ( empty( $_POST['signup_password'] ) || empty( $_POST['signup_password_confirm'] ) )
        $bp->signup->errors['signup_password'] = __( 'Please make sure you enter your password twice', 'buddypress' );

    // Check that the passwords match
    if ( ( !empty( $_POST['signup_password'] ) && !empty( $_POST['signup_password_confirm'] ) ) && $_POST['signup_password'] != $_POST['signup_password_confirm'] )
        $bp->signup->errors['signup_password'] = __( 'The passwords you entered do not match.', 'buddypress' );

    $bp->signup->username = $_POST['signup_username'];
    $bp->signup->email = $_POST['signup_email'];

    // Now we've checked account details, we can check profile information
    if ( bp_is_active( 'xprofile' ) ) {

        // Make sure hidden field is passed and populated
        if ( isset( $_POST['signup_profile_field_ids'] ) && !empty( $_POST['signup_profile_field_ids'] ) ) {

            // Let's compact any profile field info into an array
            $profile_field_ids = explode( ',', $_POST['signup_profile_field_ids'] );

            // Loop through the posted fields formatting any datebox values then validate the field
            foreach ( (array) $profile_field_ids as $field_id ) {
                if ( !isset( $_POST['field_' . $field_id] ) ) {
                    if ( !empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_day'] ) && !empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_month'] ) && !empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_year'] ) )
                        $_POST['field_' . $field_id] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_day'] . $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_month'] . $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_year'] ) );
                }

                // Create errors for required fields without values
                if ( xprofile_check_is_required_field( $field_id ) && empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id] ) )
                    $bp->signup->errors['field_' . $field_id] = __( 'This is a required field', 'buddypress' );
            }

        // This situation doesn't naturally occur so bounce to website root
        } else {
            bp_core_redirect( bp_get_root_domain() );
        }
    }

    // Finally, let's check the blog details, if the user wants a blog and blog creation is enabled
    if ( isset( $_POST['signup_with_blog'] ) ) {
        $active_signup = $bp->site_options['registration'];

        if ( 'blog' == $active_signup || 'all' == $active_signup ) {
            $blog_details = bp_core_validate_blog_signup( $_POST['signup_blog_url'], $_POST['signup_blog_title'] );

            // If there are errors with blog details, set them for display
            if ( !empty( $blog_details['errors']->errors['blogname'] ) )
                $bp->signup->errors['signup_blog_url'] = $blog_details['errors']->errors['blogname'][0];

            if ( !empty( $blog_details['errors']->errors['blog_title'] ) )
                $bp->signup->errors['signup_blog_title'] = $blog_details['errors']->errors['blog_title'][0];
        }
    }

    do_action( 'bp_signup_validate' );

    // Add any errors to the action for the field in the template for display.
    if ( !empty( $bp->signup->errors ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) $bp->signup->errors as $fieldname => $error_message ) {
            // addslashes() and stripslashes() to avoid create_function()
            // syntax errors when the $error_message contains quotes
            add_action( 'bp_' . $fieldname . '_errors', create_function( '', 'echo apply_filters(\'bp_members_signup_error_message\', "<div class=\"error\">" . stripslashes( \'' . addslashes( $error_message ) . '\' ) . "</div>" );' ) );
        }
    } else {
        $bp->signup->step = 'save-details';

        // No errors! Let's register those deets.
        $active_signup = !empty( $bp->site_options['registration'] ) ? $bp->site_options['registration'] : '';

        if ( 'none' != $active_signup ) {

            // Make sure the extended profiles module is enabled
            if ( bp_is_active( 'xprofile' ) ) {
                // Let's compact any profile field info into usermeta
                $profile_field_ids = explode( ',', $_POST['signup_profile_field_ids'] );

                // Loop through the posted fields formatting any datebox values then add to usermeta - @todo This logic should be shared with the same in xprofile_screen_edit_profile()
                foreach ( (array) $profile_field_ids as $field_id ) {
                    if ( ! isset( $_POST['field_' . $field_id] ) ) {

                        if ( ! empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_day'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_month'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_year'] ) ) {
                            // Concatenate the values
                            $date_value = $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_day'] . ' ' . $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_month'] . ' ' . $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_year'];

                            // Turn the concatenated value into a timestamp
                            $_POST['field_' . $field_id] = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $date_value ) );
                        }
                    }

                    if ( !empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id] ) )
                        $usermeta['field_' . $field_id] = $_POST['field_' . $field_id];

                    if ( !empty( $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_visibility'] ) )
                        $usermeta['field_' . $field_id . '_visibility'] = $_POST['field_' . $field_id . '_visibility'];
                }

                // Store the profile field ID's in usermeta
                $usermeta['profile_field_ids'] = $_POST['signup_profile_field_ids'];
            }

            // Hash and store the password
            $usermeta['password'] = wp_hash_password( $_POST['signup_password'] );

            // If the user decided to create a blog, save those details to usermeta
            if ( 'blog' == $active_signup || 'all' == $active_signup )
                $usermeta['public'] = ( isset( $_POST['signup_blog_privacy'] ) && 'public' == $_POST['signup_blog_privacy'] ) ? true : false;

            $usermeta = apply_filters( 'bp_signup_usermeta', $usermeta );

            // Finally, sign up the user and/or blog
            if ( isset( $_POST['signup_with_blog'] ) && is_multisite() )
                $wp_user_id = bp_core_signup_blog( $blog_details['domain'], $blog_details['path'], $blog_details['blog_title'], $_POST['signup_username'], $_POST['signup_email'], $usermeta );
            else
                $wp_user_id = bp_core_signup_user( $_POST['signup_username'], $_POST['signup_password'], $_POST['signup_email'], $usermeta );

            if ( is_wp_error( $wp_user_id ) ) {
                $bp->signup->step = 'request-details';
                bp_core_add_message( $wp_user_id->get_error_message(), 'error' );
            } else {
                $bp->signup->step = 'completed-confirmation';
            }
        }

        do_action( 'bp_complete_signup' );
    }

}

do_action( 'bp_core_screen_signup' );
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_register', array( 'register', 'registration/register' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_screens', 'bp_core_screen_signup' );
```

Now on line 98 you'll see.. 
// Add any errors to the action for the field in the template for display.

Then it loops through the errors and you come to..

```
add_action( 'bp_' . $fieldname . '_errors', create_function( '', 'echo apply_filters(\'bp_members_signup_error_message\', "<div class=\"error\">" . stripslashes( \'' . addslashes( $error_message ) . '\' ) . "</div>" );' ) );
```

I need to edit those html tags in my bp-custom.php file without reproducing the entire function. How do I hook in correctly to do this?

Comment: That last code snippet you have should be raised as a bug with the buddypress team, it's an awful piece of code

Comment: I would have no idea what to say if they asked me why.

Comment: Direct theme here, and make noises about it being the equivalent to `eval`, and anonymous functions and objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the filter hook bp_members_signup_error_message

Try:

```
function signup_error_change( $error_message ) {
     $error_message = str_replace('<div class="error">', '<span class="val-error">', $error_message);
     $error_message = str_replace('</div>', '</span>', $error_message);
     return $error_message;
}
add_filter('bp_members_signup_error_message', 'signup_error_change', 1, 1);
```

Comment: I'm confused what I'm doing in the middle for "do string find and replace". I need to change the html tags around $error_message.

Comment: I don't know what you want to change. But you can change the tags by using http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I want to change the <div> tags to <span class="val-error">.

Comment: See above, answer edited.